# Calculating percentage of project in the excel based on variables

Tags: excel

I am building an excel sheet that will calculate the progress for project, here are more details:

- Column A: Project task
- Column B:  Project status 1  ( 50%)
- Column C: Project Status 2 ( 50%)
- Column D: The Calculation of the project: if there's variable in
- Column B. The column D = 50%

If there are variables in the column B and, C ==> The column D = 100%

Here is an example:

Let's take an example for project named: coloring cars. if Column B is marked then, D automatically is 50% which means, project starts if, Column C is marked. The column D will be 100% which means project is done

Please, can you help me to build this function?

Thanks,

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have tried this function but, it seems that's not working - can you help? 
=COUNT(IF(A2:T2<>'X',A2:T2))

Comment: To be honest: I don't understand your question. Show us part of your data and the expected result. Reading [ask] will help you to enhance your question. As a side note: there is a COUNTIFS function ...

Comment: Let's take an example for project named: coloring cars. if Column B is marked then, D automatically is 50% which means, project starts if, Column C is marked. The column D will be 100% which means project is done.

Comment: In cell D2: =if(AND(B2="Y",C2="Y"),100%,if(B2="Y",50%,"not started")) but edit to your needs.

Comment: Please update your question according to your comment.

Comment: Thanks for this formula as it is working for the 100% but not the other cases, how could I add more column and, enable the calculations? 

Thanks,

Comment: Then you must have made a typo, check and edit.